# Sublime Text Snippet: Create camelcased string from the hyphenated file name

Tags: angularjs, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am trying to create a Sublime Text snippet for AngularJs.  This snippet should expand to AngularJs controller (or service, etc or any ng component).  In the resulting code, it should construct the controller name in camelCase from the hyphenated file name.

For example:

when I type the snippets strings, say, ngctrl in an empty file called employee-benefits-controller.js, it should expand as given below:

```
angular.module('').controller('EmployeeBenefitsController', ['', function(){

}]);
```

I am trying to use the $TM_FILENAME variable by applying a regex on it to achieve this conversion.  If anyone has already done this, please let us know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
angular.module('${1:moduleName}').controller('${TM_FILENAME/(^|-|\.js)(.?)|/\U\2\E/g}', ['', function(){
    ${2://functionCode}
}]);
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>ngctrl</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

---

### Notes:

Note 1: maybe you want to change the scope so that the snippet its only triggered in javascript context.

Note 2: I'm not familiar with angularjs, so I don't know its naming conventions (I have supposed that an uppercase letter its needed after a hyphen [-] character and at the begining of the name, but I don't know if a uppercase character its needed after a dot character for example). So, you'll probablly have to adapt the snippet.

Note 3: expression explained: 
**${TM_FILENAME/(^|-|.js)(.?)/\U\2\E/g}**

- **TM_FILENAME** its the var_name item
- **(^|-|.js)(.?)** its the regex (the parts of the variable we select).
- **\U\2\E** its the format_string (how we format what we have selected).
- **g** its the options (g means globally, so every time something its selected the format its given).
- **TM_FILENAME**: the file name with the extension included.
- **\U** => init uppercase conversion. **\E** => finish uppercase conversion. **\2** => second group, i.e. second parénthesis, **(.?)**, its a single char or an empty string.
- **(^|-|.js)(.?)** First we look for the beginning of the word (**^**), or for a hypen character (**-**), or for the extension (**.js**).
- **(.?)** Then we select in a parenthesis group (second group) the character (if any) after that hypen (or at the beginning of the word or after the extension).
- Finally we use the uppercase conversion over that selected character as explained. Note that as there is not character after the extension, we are simply removing the extension from the output.

Note 4: as you probablly know, using *${1:moduleName}* and *${2://functionCode}* allows you to quickly move (using tab) and edit the important parts of the snippet once it has been triggered, such as the module or the function code.